# Framerate suddenly decreases on an Android 2D game

Tags: android, 2d, textures, game-development

Thank you for reading, and my apologies for the English mistakes, I'm french

I work on a 2D game for Android, using native SDK (android.graphics).

It's a turn-by-turn game which is played on a board, so a game screen is composed of ~500 bitmaps (including board, players, ui elements, etc...).

### Technical clarifications:

The main view is a SurfaceView, each sprite displayed on screen has a Bitmap and for each frame the drawing processing is:

- get the canvas form the surface view
    `e_canvas = e_surfaceView.getHolder().lockHardwareCanvas();`
- draw on this canvas the bitmap of each sprite
  `s_canvas.drawBitmap(s_texture.getBitmap(), s_frame_rect.get(s_frame), s_dst, s_paint);`
- unlock the canvas and post
   `e_surfaceView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(e_canvas);`

### The problem:

I test on several smartphones, but the main is a Samsung Fold 3. The game works well, with a framerate of ~110fps... up to a certain point.

I don't know why, sometimes the framerate decrease to 9 fps! It seems the problem appears when  "too much" sprites are displayed on the screen. I realized a lot of tests and I don't understand what really happened but the problem always occurs when I scroll the board to a place where several obstacles are displayed.

When the framerate is bad, if a close a window of the game UI, framerate increases again.

So it is as if at a certain number of displayed sprite, the problem appears.

Strange thing, on some other smartphones (OnePlus Nord 3, OnePlus 6) all works fine, I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

### My researches:

I check with Android profiler if there is memory leak, or CPU overloaded, or other strange behavior, but I didn't notice anything.

The memory consumption remains at ~500Mo, the CPU is also stable.

So I record "System trace" and I found something interesting: when there is no problem, a "DrawFrames" of the RenderThread takes approximately 7ms (see image: [system trace when all works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tVoy.png)). But when the problem occurred, a "DrawFrames" of the RenderThread takes approximately 60ms, and it is composed of a multitude of "Texture upload". It seems at each frame all the textures are one again uploaded... although I'm n ot sure what this means. (See image: [system trace when problem occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjsfQ.png))

I don't understand what these "Texture upload" means, why they occurred at each frame? Is it a memory problem? But if it is, why the RAM consumption is the same with and without the problem? Or is it a video memory problem?